# Tables related to table T012

Tags: sap-erp

I am searching for links from bseg to T012 so that I can retrieve bank name and bank address information.

The HBKID field in bseg was empty, so I am looking for another work around.

Are there any other tables related to T012 aside from BSEG, BNKA and T012*

I tried bseg to t012 then linking to bnka. but the hbkid field in the bseg was empty.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: One document has several lines in BSEG. Don't you see the bank ID in other lines of BSEG for the same document number? (PS: HBKID = "bank ID")

Comment: No single record with HBKID, do you know any other links to get the House Bank ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to try this way:

1. Pick vendor data (LIFNR) from `BSEG`
2. Go with that data to table `REGUH` where settlement data pays
3. Get `HBKID` from `REGUH`

[image]

Additionally, [this can be the reason](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3558536) why house bank is not saved in FI documents, it depends on transaction they are created with.

Also check maintenance of "Payment Transactions" in vendor master data (XK02), it can conflict with Bank determination in FBZP.